# doxygen - how to multi-line a file documentation enum?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to document some c++ enum like this:

```
/** Members */
enum {
  MEMBER_ONE, /*!< This is member one */
  MEMBER_TWO  /*!< This is member two */
} members;
```

the documentation looks good but the problem is that the code with the hyperlinks to the documentation (I'm talking of the section in the File Documentation like the following:

> File Documentation
>
> file1.h
>
> enum { MEMBER_ONE, MEMBER_TWO };

doesn't have any newline among all the members of the enum source code. Any way to force doxygen respecting the newlines or inserting them? Putting 
 inside the comments only works for the documentation itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doxygen reformats the enum's values, but you can control how many elements will appear on a line via the `ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE` configuration option. So you could set it to 1 to get one item per line as was in the original source code.

Comment: thanks! My target was the latex PDF more than the HTML documentation, any chance to do that on the tex files?